# Identification of light nuclei in heavy nuclei collisions

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-accelerators

At the LHC, apart from proton collisions, there are heavy ion collisions. Imagine that we have two beams of Fe nuclei. In the collision there would be lighter ions produced and I was wondering:

1. How is the principle used in their separation, is it only that they have a different charge or also other properties as different radiation length.
2. Can we measure the cross-section for these lighter ions by measuring their resulting mass?

Comment: The LHC has seven experiments that do heavy ion physics: ATLAS, CMS, ALICE, LHCb, TOTEM, LHCf, and MoEDAL. The details are different for each experiment, so you probably need to be a bit more specific here.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I would like to know _in general_ how is the resulting particle separation performed and specially if we can measure the cross-section of lighter particles there.

In general, I'm interested on measuring of cross-section measurements of light species to use them for spallation calculation of cosmic rays. I know for example that the uncertainties on the measurement of Berilium, Boron,... cross-sections at energies >GeV are large and was wondering wether they could be measured using the collision of Fe atoms.

Comment: Fe-Fe collisions would be useful for that if cosmic rays were iron nuclei and they hit iron atoms on earth. As it is, cosmic rays are all light nuclei and most of what they hit is not iron, so there's not really any direct comparison.

Comment: Cosmic rays are _not_ all light nuclei, in fact, the composition close to the GZK cut-off is looking more Fe-like than H-like using the latest data. Anyways, my questions stand: what is the principle used for the separation of these particles in a calorimeter and can we measure any properties derived from the measurements of their mass as the cross-section?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, interesting. Mostly light nuclei is fair to say, though? Anyway, most of my experience is with proton-proton collisions, so I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that mass measurement is done in the tracking system, not the calorimeter. The calorimeter only gives you a kinetic energy measurement, while tracking in a magnetic field gives you the mass-to-charge ratio.

Comment: read on page 5 of this alice summary the number of ways particles are identified in ALICE  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4291.pdf .  I have not seen production crossections for larger nuclei  than helium and antihelium.